# Error in first computation of text width using HTML5 measureText() with a custom font

Tags: javascript, fonts, html5-canvas

I'm building a 2D top-down turn-based soccer game. Every time you click a player of your team, a card is drawn on a side canvas. I've just started the code for such cards and as a preliminary action it just draws the template with the selected player's name horizontally centered:

```
drawPlayerCard = (card, player) => {
    let ctx = this.leftUserContext;
    ctx.drawImage(card.template, card.position.x, card.position.y);
    const nameWidth = ctx.measureText(player.name).width;
    ctx.font = "12px fff";
    ctx.fillText(player.name, ((card.template.width - nameWidth) / 2) + card.position.x, (202 + card.position.y));
}
```

The font is a free font I downloaded and put in use through CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: fff;
    src: url(../font/fff-forward.regular.ttf);
}

body {
    font-family: fff;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

and an old HTML trick I've found here on SO to get the font to preload:

```
<div id="TableSoccer">
    <canvas class="board" id="Field" width="1488" height="1008"></canvas>
    <canvas class="board" id="Players" width="1488" height="1008"></canvas>
    <canvas class="board" id="MouseEvents" width="1488" height="1008"></canvas>
    <canvas class="user left" id="LeftUser" width="200" height="1008"></canvas>
    <canvas class="user right" id="RightUser" width="200" height="1008"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="font-family:'fff'">&nbsp;</div> <!-- font preload -->
```

However, the *first time* I click on a player, the name on the card is centered using a default font size instead of the custom's one, that still is correctly loaded and shown:

This is the result at the first click with custom font loaded:

[image]

This is the result at further clicks with custom font loaded:

[image]

This is the result at the first click with default font. I commented out the `ctx.font = "12px fff"` line and the resulting text it's perfectly centered, so my assumption about the default font size used for the first measure is correct:

[image]

I think this has something to do with asynchronous loading of the font but I don't get why because the font is actually loaded and shown.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the order of the operations matters.

If you do:

```
const nameWidth = ctx.measureText(player.name).width;
ctx.font = "12px fff";
```

you're setting the context to a different font **after** measuring the text. So it will return the width of whatever font the context has been set to previously or use the default. On subsequent calls to the `drawPlayerCard()` method the context's font will be set to `'fff'` and thus return the correct width.

So simply change the above to this:

```
ctx.font = "12px fff";
const nameWidth = ctx.measureText(player.name).width;
```

Comment: I feel **so** dumb! Thanks!!

Comment: No problem Davide - glad I could help! =)